# How can I delete/cancel an job/event in bi-weekly

Tags: java, icalendar

Is there any way to delete and event using bi-weekly library? I am able to schedule an event. But i am unable to find cancelling or deleting in their docs.

I want to cancel an event via java webapp.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it via this link:
https://github.com/mangstadt/biweekly/wiki/Examples#cancelling-an-event

```
ICalendar ical = new ICalendar();
VEvent event = new VEvent();
event.setStatus(Status.cancelled());
event.setUid(...);    //the UID of the existing event
event.setSequence(2); //increment the sequence number of the existing event
ical.addEvent(event);
```